# d3.js: Change x-axis interval on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I've got this pair of axes that are nearly working the way I want them to, but there's a small, peculiar error.

I've got the graph configured to change the x-axis interval depending on which one of these nav-pills are selected, and it does this but it requires two clicks for the changes to render.

You can see a slightly working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zreqz/3/

Basically, the meat of this problem lies in the code towards the bottom of the JavaScript:

```
$("li").on("click", function () {
    $("#chart").empty();
    renderGraph();
});
```

So the steps are:

1. Click one of the pills
2. Clear the graph from the DOM
3. Re-render the graph and determine which pill is active, form the x-axis domain based on that:

   ```
   getIntervalType = function () {
     if ($("#hours").hasClass("active")) {
       return startTimeHour;
     } else if ($("#days").hasClass("active")) {
       return startTimeDay;
     } else if ($("#months").hasClass("active")) {
       return startTimeMonth;
     }
   };
   ```

Anyone know a solution to getting the graph to re-render correctly on the first click?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't seem to work.  The chart is hardcoded and the d3 code is in a function called "graphFunction" that doesn't seem to be called anywhere.

Comment: @ScottCameron, sorry about that, bad copying and pasting on my part. It should be updated and working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class of the clicked element doesn't update until after the callback you've defined has finished - ie, after renderGraph() has already been called.

Setting the classes manually avoids this problem:

```
d3.selectAll('li').on('click', function(){
    d3.selectAll('.active').classed('active', false);
    d3.select(this).classed('active', true);
    d3.select('#chart').select('svg').remove();
    renderGraph();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zreqz/5/

Comment: Hey, thanks! This works great. I actually came up with another working solution before seeing this one. If you're interested: http://jsfiddle.net/zreqz/4/